# Drawing a UILabel with Transformations

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have a `UILabel` (but this should apply to any `UIView`). I am trying to draw a label to a `UIImage`.

First, I've applied a transformation to a label:

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,100,100))
label.text = "Fizz Buzz"
label.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(label.transform, 5)
label.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(label.transform, 2, 2)
label.setTranslation(CGPointMake(10, 15), inView: view)
```

Then, I want to draw the label to an Image.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.frame.size, false, 0)
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
label.drawTextInRect(view.frame)
let result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Now, the `result` UIImage that appears is an image of the label with the proper text, but without a the transformation.  How do I ensure that the view draws with the transforms?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the current UIImage data not just the frame to be able to add text to that image. I have a simple function below that adds text to an image. If you are using a UIImageView , you can get the currently assigned image to it, passed it to the function and set the image returned by the function to that UIImageView.

```
extension UILabel
{
  func getRenderedImage() -> UIImage
  {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.frame.size, false, 0)

    var context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    CGContextSaveGState(context)

    self.layer.renderInContext(context!)

    let renderedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return renderedImage
  }
}
```

Sample Usage:

```
let newImage = label.getRenderedImage()
imagView.image = newImage
```

Comment: Hmm, this will probably work, but my way of drawing to the UILabel to the Image does actually *almost* work, it just doesn't apply the proper transformation that I've made to the view. Is there no way to continue using the label and just transform the label as it's drawn?

Comment: please post your other code as it is hard to fully understand your problem by just looking at that one line of code you posted. thanks.

Comment: I updated my answer. I made an extension to UILabel which will return the currently rendered data inside the UILabel Layer. But I think there is a problem with using transformation as it is not reflecting right away in the UILabel's layer.

Comment: This did not solve the problem, as this method still does not maintain transformations applied to it when drawn. However I did discover a solution. Thank you for your attempts.

Comment: I saw that article too where he used a wrapper view to render the image.  I am still wondering why it won't reflect the layer did not include the transformations made. Anyway, it is good that it's working now. :)

Answer (score 0):

To start a small change should be made in the 3rd line of the second code snippet. Replace `label.drawTextInRect(view.frame)` with `label.drawTextInRect(label.frame)`.

However to properly maintain the transformations, I discovered the easiest way was to create a wrapper UIView. Still apply the transformations to the label, but draw the wrapper view to a UIImage instead of the label. Use the line:

```
wrapperView.drawViewHierarchyInRect(wrapperView.frame, afterScreenUpdates: true)
```